# Fancytree not visible has class ui-helper-hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I have just started with fancytree 2.6.0 and I am populating it from a web service request.

My problem is that all the nodes are present but are made invisible by the ui-helper-hidden class. I have put in a temporary fix with: $(rootNode.ul).removeClass('ui-helper-hidden'); but I am sure I am missing something.

The scripts and css:

```
<link href="Scripts/jquery-plugins/fancytree-2.6.0/src/skin-themeroller/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-plugins/fancytree-2.6.0/src/jquery.fancytree.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-plugins/fancytree-2.6.0/src/jquery.fancytree.themeroller.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

The code:

```
$('#selectedClausesDiv').fancytree();

$.when(
    $.getJSON("Handlers/GetQuotationHandler.ashx?jsoncallback=?", { quoteReference: quoteReference, quoteVersion: quoteVersion })
).then(function (data) {
    if (data.ErrorCode == 0 && data.Quotation != null) {
        var rootNode = $("#selectedClausesDiv").fancytree("getRootNode");
        $.each(data.Quotation.Covers, function (index, item) {
            addCover(rootNode, item);
        });

        // FIXME: why is this necessary ??
        // $(rootNode.ul).removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');
    }
});

function addCover(rootNode, cover) {
    var coverId = 'selected_' + cover.BusinessClassId + '_' + cover.CoverId;

    var coverNode = rootNode.addChildren({
        title: cover.Name,
        tooltip: "This folder and all child nodes were added programmatically.",
        folder: true
    });
}
```

The generated html:

```
<div class="grid_13 alpha omega" id="selectedClausesDiv">
    <ul class="ui-fancytree fancytree-container ui-fancytree-source ui-helper-hidden" tabindex="0">
        <li class="">
            <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-folder fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-cf">
                <span class="fancytree-expander"/>
                <span class="fancytree-icon"/>
                <span title="This folder and all child nodes were added programmatically." class="fancytree-title">P&amp;I Owned</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="fancytree-lastsib">
            <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-folder fancytree-lastsib fancytree-exp-nl fancytree-ico-cf">
                <span class="fancytree-expander"/>
                <span class="fancytree-icon"/>
                <span title="This folder and all child nodes were added programmatically." class="fancytree-title">P&amp;I Extended Cargo</span>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Fancytree will automatically hide the root element if no data source is provided.

If you are adding data using the API and no initial source, providing a blank `source` option will prevent Fancytree from hiding the root element.

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    source: []
});
```